# What was the impact of Fischer vs. Spassky 1972 on the relationship between the USA and the Soviet Union?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, political-history, cold-war, sports

In 1948, the Fédération Internationale des Échecs ([FIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE)) organized the first [Chess World Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1948) after WW2. Its winner was [Mikhail Botvinnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Botvinnik). Further Chess World Champions were [Vasily Smyslov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Smyslov), [Mikhail Tal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Tal), [Tigran Petrosian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigran_Petrosian) and [Boris Spassky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Spassky). All of them represented the [Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Union).

But in 1972, Spassky faced [Robert James Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby_Fischer) in the [Match of the Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1972) and lost. In the [middle of the Cold War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_events_in_the_Cold_War), with the Vietnam war still raging.

In an [interview](https://conversationswithbillkristol.org/transcript/garry-kasparov-transcript/) with Bill Kristol (I. Chess and Politics in Soviet Russia, Conversations with Bill Kristol, 2016), former Chess World Champion [Garry Kasparov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Kasparov) said

> That’s why the Spassky defeat – Boris Spassky’s defeat in 1972 when Bobby Fischer took the crown from the hands of the Soviet Chess School. Since 1948, you know, chess title was firmly in the hands of Soviet players. This event was treated by people on both sides of the Atlantic as a crushing moment in the midst of the Cold War. Big intellectual victory for the United States, and you know, a hugely painful, almost insulting defeat for the Soviet Union, because Bobby Fischer was a great player but he was like a lonely warrior. A guy from Brooklyn taking on the mighty Soviet Chess School.

Kasparov calls it a **crushing moment**.

That's also quoted by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1972), speaking of the "global significance of the match". And the [Cold War timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_events_in_the_Cold_War#1972) also includes it. But there's nothing further on it in the match article's section on the [Aftermath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Chess_Championship_1972#Aftermath) (just about chess). So Kasparov's quote is all we got and he was born in 1963, i. e. was 9 years old when Fischer won the match.

**Did the 1972 Chess World Championship influence the relationship between the USA and the Soviet Union and if so, how?**

Comment: I should point out that Bill Kristol is famous among the US punditocracy for **always being wrong**. Seriously. A web search for "Bill Kristol is always wrong" today brought me hits from diverse sources such as Salon, the WaPo, an Austrian Economics website, The Federalist, and Rachel Maddow. Jon Stewart asked him to his face in an interview, "Are you ever right?" I've seen his continued employment cited as conclusive proof against meritocracy.

Comment: @T.E.D. I quoted the transcript, but even when you listen to the interview (don't worry, it's right there at the beginning, maybe 1 min and 30 sec in), Kasparov himself said that, not Kristol.

Comment: Ah, that's better. Kasparov these days mostly surfaces publicly to take calculated political digs at Putin and those who deal with him. Not a fan of Putin myself, but I always wonder exactly what chess move Kasparov is making with his statements (and that includes this one). Still, in my experience, even his punditry about US politics has a far better track record of accuracy than Kristol's.

Comment: @T.E.D. I have found an incidence of Kristol actually being *right*. On Trump's election he said, "He’s unlikely to be a good president, from my point of view, either in terms of his character and judgement or many of his policies,"

Comment: @LarsBosteen - [citation needed]

Comment: @T.E.D. Source seems to be Lucy Whitney's March 2017 [article](https://www.cavalierdaily.com/article/2017/04/political-commentator-william-kristol-talks-donald-trump-on-american-forum) for *The Cavalier Daily*.

Comment: @IndianaJenna Yep, you got in there just before me. ;)

Comment: @T.E.D. Don't get me wrong, I'm not familiar enough with Kristol to have an opinion either way. Just thought his comment on Trump was spot on. :)

Comment: @LarsBosteen - In Basketball and Soccer tap-ins count the same. Punditry, I'm not so sure...

Comment: The very first sentence of the question is misleading.  What was special about the tournament in 1948 was not that it was the first post-WWII championship, but that the reigning champion, Alekhine, had died and needed to be replaced by some means other than a challenge match.

Comment: This was unlike the situation in 1975 when Fisher refused to defend because prior to this time there was no candidates' tournament.  The champion decided which challenge to accept, which is hard to do when he's dead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Minimal, it would seem. Hype and temporary 'bragging rights' aside, the championship was politically (not to mention economically) insignificant compared to events which happened just before, during or shortly after, such as President [Nixon's visit to Moscow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Summit_(1972)) in May 1972, [SALT I / II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Arms_Limitation_Talks#SALT_I_Treaty), and the [1973 oil crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_oil_crisis). A period of [US - Soviet détente](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1969-1976/detente) was already underway and would continue until the late 1970s. Détente may have facilitated the Fischer - Spassky showdown, but the showdown had no discernible effect on détente, however big a news story it was at the time.

---

In the New Yorker article [*Game Theory: Spassky vs. Fischer revisited*](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2004/03/01/game-theory) which reviews David Edmonds and John Eidinow's book *[Bobby Fischer Goes to War: How the Soviets Lost the Most Extraordinary Chess Match of All Time](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780060510244)*, professor and Pulitzer Prize for History winner [Louis Menand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Menand) notes that:

> One possible reason for the world’s interest was the Cold War, and for
> most of their book Edmonds and Eidinow play up the Cold War aspects of
> the match. This makes it a little surprising when, at the end, they
> discount the whole idea.

In the words of the book's authors (Edmonds and Eidinow),

> ...the championship took place in the high blossoming of
> détente....Though almost all accounts of Fischer-Spassky couch the
> match in geopolitical terms, they are, in this respect, curiously
> misleading. The encounter might have been seen by the public and
> written up by the press as a cold war showdown, but in the kremlin and
> in the White House, East-West showdowns were not on the agenda.

According to the article, the authors argue that, on an official level, neither the Americans nor the Soviets were enamoured with their respective 'representatives':

> American officials, on their side, regarded Fischer mainly with fear
> and loathing. [Then National Security advisor Henry] [Kissinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Kissinger)’s intervention seems to have been motivated by
> personal interest in the game, rather than by grand strategy. The
> State Department informed the American chargé d’affaires in Reykjavík
> to spend no government resources on Fischer’s behalf, and the chargé’s
> own deepest desire was to get Fischer off the island as quickly as
> possible....
>
> And, on the other side, Spassky was far from a typical Soviet-era
> athlete. He was a patriot, but a Russian patriot. He hated the
> Bolsheviks and had little respect for the Soviet system (though he was
> careful to extract the rewards to which he believed his
> accomplishments as a sportsman entitled him). It gave him pleasure to
> ignore advice offered by Soviet officials, and in Iceland he made his
> seconds and other handlers miserable with frustration by his
> insistence on doing things his own way.

Further, there was apparently no evidence that either the Americans or the Soviets tried anything 'underhand'; it seems that neither side thought the stakes were particularly high in terms of the Cold War:

> Edmonds and Eidinow speculate vigorously, but they can’t find any
> proof that the K.G.B., or anyone on Fischer’s team, did anything
> underhanded. They also conclude, somewhat reluctantly, that official
> Soviet involvement in the match was not unusually intense, and that
> the press coverage was entirely non-ideological. This was, they
> properly note, a period of superpower détente.

As a consequence of losing,

> Back in Moscow, Spassky and his team were subjected to a humiliating
> postmortem, and Spassky’s travel privileges were suspended (a standard
> Soviet response to failure in international competition).

Fischer, [on the other hand](https://deepchess.org/blog/f/the-match-of-the-century-fischer-spassky-1972),

> was received in the U.S. as a national hero — Richard Nixon
> sent him a congratulatory telegram, inviting him to the White House.

But this was [short-lived and](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2004/03/01/game-theory)

> After...a few grudging public appearances,... Fischer went off the radar
> screen.

So, while the world may have been "hooked' for a while, only the game of chess seems to have been affected. The profile of chess rose in America, as it did in other countries. Fischer forfeited his title in 1975 and [Anatoly Karpov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Karpov#Rivalry_with_Kasparov) dominated the chess scene for the next 10 years (1975-85).

---

If you are looking for a sporting event which did have an impact on political events, the best candidate would probably be the 1969 [Football War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_War#Buildup) between El Salvador and Honduras, but even here the football match in question was more a symptom of other, underlying, causes. Also of interest is the [India–Pakistan cricket rivalry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93Pakistan_cricket_rivalry), but here the sport has generally served more to calm relations than inflame them (despite the intense rivalry).

Comment: Agreed. While the match made a lot of news at the time, it soon became clear that Fischer was, at best, eccentric, and unrepresentative of the US way of doing things,

Comment: @JohnDallman: I would say that the US way of doing things is coming to resemble Fischer's modus operandi more and more closely!

Comment: There have also been times when politics impacted the outcome of a sporting event, most notoriously an event that happened the same year as the Fischer-Spassky match, namely the 1972 Olympic gold medal game in basketball.

Comment: @CMonsour  exactly.  Never wonder why Americans distrust international bodies.

Comment: @CMonsour - As someone who played on a largely African American soccer team in Oklahoma just after Jim Crow ended. I've never been particularly upset by that game. Yes officials have biases, and if you let a game be close, that will often be the decider. That's sport. You can't change who you are, and you can't change their heads. The answer is, if you are really the better team, don't let the game be close.

Comment: @T.E.D.  If the Americans had been clotheslining Soviet players the way the Soviets did to Jim Brewer maybe it wouldn't have been close.  Anyway, no one remembers when people cheat and lose anyway (and no one who is clever cheats when it won't enable them to win).  It's the close ones that matter.  But my point was that if that game didn't have political ramifications, a chess match between two people no one in either country much liked sure wasn't going to.

Comment: @CMonsour - ..but the refs would have called that on the Americans, which they knew so they didn't do it. I once played in a championship game in Oklahoma in the '70's where the other team was given a soft PK, then the white kid was allowed to retake the PK 3 times until he put it in due to our keeper "moving off his line", a call I never saw again until [this current World Cup](https://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2019/jun/20/var-penalising-goalkeepers-unfairly-womens-world-cup) (40 years later). Ref bias is just another day ending in "y".

Comment: Insightful reference about the India-Pakistan cricket rivalry. There's been a hiatus for many years and teams stopped visiting each other's countries. It's interesting to see escalations in recent years like the 2019 stand-off where they shot aircraft down and had fuelled up missiles.

Comment: @T.E.D. Maybe, but considering the basketball game was played *barely more than a week after the end of the Fisher-Spassky match*, I think there may have been payback involved.  Anyway, that is probably the fullest extent of the Fisher-Spassky match as a causal factor in anything outside of chess.

Comment: On Spassky not being a supporter of the Soviet system, it's worth noting that he and Botvinnik were the only famous Soviet chess players who refused to sign the letter condemning Korchnoi for defecting in 1974.  Subsequently, Spassky emigrated to France in 1976 and only moved back to Russia in 2012, long after the fall of the USSR.  According to Wikipedia, he describes himself as "a Christian and a monarchist", two qualities that would definitely not have endeared him to the Soviet authorities.